# Update two rows from one subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-update

@tmp table has two rows with two codes
local1 has values for both the codes 
I should update @tmp with the sum for both the rows respective to their codes

```
update @tmp set col1=(select sum (isnull(((isnull(e1,0.00)/100.00)
                                                * (isnull(e2, 0))),0.00))  
                from    @tmp tp left join
                        local1 l(nolock) 
                  on    l.code = tp.code    
                where   emp_code        = 123
                group by code )
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Microsoft SQL server management studio 2016 @jarlh

Comment: FYI SSMS is just the client interface and doesn't imply anything about the database engine it is connected to.

Comment: @Mjv . . . Sample data and desired results would really help.  Your formula looks much much complicated than a simple sum.  And your query refers to many more columns than 2.

Answer (score 1):

One option uses window functions and an updatable cte:

```
with cte as (select col1, sum(e1) over(partition by code) new_col1 from emp_code)
update cte set col1 = coalesce(new_col1, 0)
```